# Schema-validation: missing table while it exists

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

Briefly, Hibernate does not see the columns in the 'accounts' table (PostgreSQL), but the table exists and the columns in it too. When you try to comment out a column field, Hibernate does not see the next field, and so on until there is not one left. I decided to recreate this table, include it in the @ManyToOne relation with the newly created account_groups table, but now an exception is thrown
SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [royal_user.account_groups]
Between account_groups and accounts there is a unidirectional @OneToMany in account_groups. There are tables in the DB, I'm sure it's not a case problem in the title. Tell me, please, what could be the problem? I am attaching the entity classes below.

**UserEntity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users", schema = "royal_user")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UserEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_id", unique = true)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, unique = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "surname", nullable = false, unique = false)
    private String surname;
    @Column(name = "patronymic", nullable = true, unique = false)
    private String patronymic;
    @Column(name = "date_of_birth", nullable = false, unique = false)
    private String dateOfBirth;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "passport_id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private PassportEntity passportEntity;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "accounts_group_id")
    private AccountGroupsEntity accountGroupsEntity;
    @Column(name = "hashcode", nullable = false, unique = false)
    private String hashcode;
    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;

    //some code
 }
```

**AccountEntity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "accounts", schema = "royal_user")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class AccountEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "account_id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "currency")
    private String currency;
    @Column(name = "amount")
    private int amount;
    @Column(name = "account_opening_date")
    private String accountOpeningDate;
    @Column(name = "account_closing_date")
    private String accountClosingDate;

   //some code
 }
```

**AccountGroupsEntity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "account_groups", schema = "royal_user")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class AccountGroupsEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "group_id")
    private int groupId;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "accounts_id")
    private List<AccountEntity> accounts;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "accountGroupsEntity")
    private UserEntity userEntity;
    
   //some code
 }
```

I forgot to fix the database in hibernate.config.xml from the test database to the current one, the problem with AccountsEntity, indicated at the beginning of the text, was repeated, namely Schema-validation: missing column [account_closing_date] in table [royal_user.accounts].

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">*connection_url*</property>
        <property name="connection.username">some_name</property>
        <property name="connection.password">some_password</property>


        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- Print executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Update database on startup -->
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>

        <!-- Annotated entity classes -->
        <mapping class="restServiceOne.hibernate.entity.UserEntity" />
        <mapping class="restServiceOne.hibernate.entity.PassportEntity"/>
        <mapping class="restServiceOne.hibernate.entity.AddressEntity"/>
        <mapping class="restServiceOne.hibernate.entity.AccountEntity"/>
        <mapping class="restServiceOne.hibernate.entity.AccountGroupsEntity"/>


    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Might help to see your Hibernate config properties as well as the exact error you're getting.

Comment: When you look at the DB are you sure you're looking at the same schema (`royal_user`)? And are the login credentials the same as you've configured for the application?

Comment: @E-Riz I edited question so I added content of hibernate.cfg.xml

Comment: @E-Riz omg, I see that in DB two shemas called "royal_user", I didn't noticed it before, I guess that might be a solution